# SumIf using dates and ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum a row biased on the fact that another row has the same month as a variable that is defined by the user. I believe the sumif function would be my best bet but it doesn't seem to be working for me. The row I want it to look at obviously is a row of Date with date formatting (used .numberformat = "ddd mm/dd") but the sumif doesn't seem to be able to pick out the month in each cell. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim cMade As Integer
Dim sDate As Date
 cMade = cMade + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Range("B1:RC1"), Month(sDate), ActiveSheet.Range("B30:RC30"))
```

As you can see sDate is the date that the user imputs via userform then i convert that using dateserial. and B1-RC1 are the dates i want it to look at. And Range B30-RC30 are the sums i want it to grab if the months match up (the reason I have it as + cMade is because it is in a loop that loops through sheets).

Is this code correct? I have been messing with it and looking for alternatives for hours but I cant not seem to come up with anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is only a part of your code and I may only guess the rest, try the following corrections:

1. I think you should define `Range("B30,RC30")` as `Range("B30:RC30")` - comma here looks like a typo according to the description.
2. Replace `Application.SumIf` with `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf`.

As an addition, consider to define ranges more precise, e.g. via `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")` or `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C10")` syntax. However, this may be an extra measure - I don't see the rest of your code.

Hope that was somehow helpful.

Comment: hmm thanks for the help I did need to correct these things but it for some reason cMade is always 0, as if I am not pointing the sumif to the correct sum row (which I am certain I am).

Comment: Could you please share your current `cMade = ...` string?

Comment: I have noticed that if I try and just use the sumif function in a worksheet to test it ex: =Sumif(B1:J1,Month(1),B30:J30) it still gives me a value of zero.

I updated the orginal question with my new string.

Comment: @MainTank `MONTH` should have as an argument actual `Date` value, are you sure you should use `1`? Or simply share me your workbook)

Comment: I am not 100% on that. I am pretty new to this site how do I share my workbook?

Comment: @MainTank using dropbox or any similar tool and just dropping the link here.

Comment: Okay I uploaded it to dropbox. This should be the link [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrafbs0zyw1o0nh/Book1.1.xlsm . As you will see I have a lot going on but the specific issue I am talking about is under the CreateReport userform.

Comment: @MainTank I think I got the clue: `=SUMIF(B1:J1,MONTH(1),B30:J30)` will always return 0 since you try to compare **Dates** in B1:J1 with MONTH value, which is 1..12. I think you just need to update either condition or initial range data.

Comment: I think your right! Now I am using Dateserial() instead of Month() as the condition. And it seems like it will work. Now I just have to figure out how to make the day not a factor. Thank you I have been working on this for hours!!

Comment: I know I need reputation to do that :(

Comment: @MainTank no you don't - accept answers is allowed for just 1 rep. Just tick the answer under its score. BTW, after that you'll get +2 and therefore total 15 - that gives you privilege for upvoting.

Comment: @MainTank Good luck with your code buddy! Start a new thread in case stuck with smth else.